# Powershell Get-ACL

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Get-ACL with a CSV file that has a list of shares from different filers.
Individual string that works is:
Get-Acl \\server\path | Format-List -Property AccessToString

Format of the CSV is like so:
\\servername\path

How would I get powershell to loop through the CSV file and put the output into the same or an entirely new file?

This is my attempt thus far:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\TestPath.csv"
ForEach ($file in $file1) {
   $infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullPAth | Format-List -Property AccessToString
   $file | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\newTestPath.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read and reformat. Give us some attempt at code and welcome.

Comment: @dcaz This suffice?

Comment: The `Format-*` cmdlets should only be used for displaying text to the console. Line 4 would be better (IMO) if you remove the pipe and everything after it on line 3, then do line 4 as `$infoSec.Access | Select @{l='File';e={$file.FullPath}},* | Export-Csv <your parameters>`

Comment: Seems to be working thanks! I figured out